# How to create Django project in Windows?

Tags: python, django

I tried of creating project in Windows. When I type `django-admin.py startproject projectname` it takes but it won't created in folder. Everything is installed and previous project also running fine.

Comment: Is your command prompt in the right folder?

Answer (score 4):

instead of `django-admin.py startproject projectname`, use

`django-admin startproject projectname`

In windows, open folder where you want to create the project, point to empty space and press `Shift` and then right mouse click. Choose the option `Open Command Window Here`. Then in command window, just enter above command.

Comment: But it's not working .Same thing happening what was before

Comment: Well, if you understood my answer and doing accordingly, you need to check your python and django installation.

Answer (score 3):

in windows 10 try running below command for python version 3.6 and higher from windows powershell:

```
python -m django startproject django_project_1
```